# How to compare set() and list() in Google Or Tools?

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, or-tools

I am working on specific multi bin knapsack problem using Google Or Tools.

One of constraints assumes that **items are split into parts** and **only one part of item can be stored in single bin**.

I've created additional list that represents item ids. So, for example:

```py
items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
item_ids = [1, 1, 2, 2]
```

means that we have two items splitted into 2 parts each.

After that I want to use constraint that forces list of stored items ids to be the same as set of stored items ids.

Something like:

```py
solver.Add(
   [matrix[i][j] * data['items_ids'][i] for i in data['items']] == \
   list(set([matrix[i][j] * data['items_ids'][i] for i in data['items']]))
)
```

(`data` is dictionary like in https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/multiple_knapsack)

And I am getting error below:

```py
    File "optimiser.py", line 111, in define_constrains
      list(set([matrix[i][j] * data['items_ids'][i] for i in data['items']]))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'ProductCst'
```

I believe it's because result of `matrix[i][j] * data['items_ids'][i]` is not a number but Google Or Tools class but I have no idea how to get list of unique values of Google Or tools variables.

Comment: Without trying to analyze your code (wich looks strange conceptionally): If your core is a binary-decision matrix, just add decomposed implications. For each bin B, item 1 @ B -> not item 2 @ B, ... This doesn't touch or-tools but is a simple python preprocessing task. Get unique set of item_ids and for each set: get mapped items -> all 2-combinations (itertools) and add those implications. There won't be any list / set or similar stuff touching or-tools. It's also a hard-constraint and doesn't need to be connected to costs / objective.

Comment: The solver expects a linear constraints: `sum(var[i] * coeff[i]) == value`, not an array/matrix/list/set of linear constraints.

Comment: And in regards to the error: It seems you want to enforce equality between a (left hand side) weighted variable = *linear-expression resolving to a scalar* and a (right hand side) list which doesn't make any sense, even if being constrained to *dimensionality* only. or-tools is not doing *dimensionality-repairing tricks like numpy's broadcasting* as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by changing conception of solution.

As @sascha mentioned in comments, Or-tools is not doing dimensionality-repairing tricks so I've changed my approach.

I've added constraint for every part of item:

```py
def item_parts_in_bin(i, j, data, matrix):
    return sum(
        matrix[_i][j] for _i in data['items']
        if data['item_ids'][i] == data['item_ids'][_i]
    )

for i in data['items']:
    solver.Add(
        item_parts_in_bin(i, j, data, matrix) <= 1
    )
```

So basically it returns count of item parts of same item id placed in bin. This sum must be <= 1 that means that only one part of item can be in the bin at the same time.